# Preciso que el valor de mi variable globlal, se vaya actualizando, y que la resta realizada dentro del if, se realice respecto al nuevo valor

Tags: javascript

la variable global es stockGlobal, y quiero que si mi condicion (if) se cumple, se haga la operacion dentro de mi if, y que el valor de stockGlobal se actualice.
Nuevamente, si mi condicion (if) se cumple, quiero que se haga la operacion dentro de mi, que en este caso es una resta, pero que se haga al nuevo valor de stock global.
Por ejemplo,

`stock = 500`
`cantidad compra = 50`
`stockGlobal = stock;`
`StockGlobal = stockGlobal - cantidadCompra`
en este caso el nuevo valor de stock global seria de 450, y en caso de volver a realizar la operacion, stockGlobal = 450 - cantidadCompra = 50 = stockGlobal 400, y asi sucesivamente

```
   let stockGlobal = 0;
    
function ej25Comprar(){

    let stock = ej25Stock();
    let cantidadCompra = Number(document.querySelector("#txtCantidad").value);
    
    stockGlobal = stock;

    
    if(cantidadCompra <= stockGlobal){
        stockGlobal = stockGlobal - cantidadCompra;
        
        console.log(stockGlobal);
```

Comment: en si es lo mismo, la variable let stockGlobal ya es global porque esta declarada por fuera de mi function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya pude solucionarlo, hice algo parecido a lo que me enviaste, el problema que tenia era que el valor que yo tomaba como stockInicial estaba declarado en otra function, y yo le estaba asignando el valor a mi sotckGlobal dentro una funcion distinta a la que estaba declarado el stockInicial.
Lo que hice fue, le asigne el valor de stockInicial a stockGlobal dentro de la function de stockInicial, entonces al momento de utilizar la variable stockGlobal dentro de mi otra funcion, tomaba y actualizaba bien el dato.

```
var stockGlobal = 0;

function ej25Stock(){
    let stockInicial = Number(document.querySelector("#txtStock").value);
    
    stockGlobal = stockInicial;
}

function ej25Comprar(){
   let cantidadCompra = Number(document.querySelector("#txtCantidad").value);

   if(cantidadCompra <= stockGlobal){
       stockGlobal = stockGlobal - cantidadCompra;
}
```

De esta manera, la variable stockGlobal, se actualizaba, y la operacion dentro del if le restaba la cantidadCompra al nuevo valor de stockGlobal, y asi sucesivamente.

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que cuando ejecutas la función ej25Comprar le estás asignando a la variable stock el resultado de la función ej25Stock(que supongo que devuelve la cantidad de stock que hay disponible). Creo que una solución para ese problema sería de la siguiente manera:

```
let stockGlobal = ej25Stock();
function ej25Comprar(){
   let cantidadCompra = Number(document.querySelector("#txtCantidad").value);
   if(cantidadCompra <= stockGlobal){
       stockGlobal = stockGlobal - cantidadCompra;
       console.log(stockGlobal);
}
```

De esta manera cuando ejecutes la función:

```
ej25Comprar(); //Salida: 450
ej25Comprar(); //Salida: 400
```

Comment: Buenas Alejandro, pude solucionarlo, realice una respuesta a mi propia pregunta por si te queres fijar, es parecido a lo que me respondiste, muchas gracias!